# Check if sub image exists in main image with PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, image, gdlib

Using PHP, how can I check whether an image exists within another?

Example:

How can I check whether subimage.jpg exists within mainimage.jpg, using PHP?

1. subimage.jpg

   [image: subimage.jpg]
2. mainimage.jpg

   [image: mainimage.jpg]

Comment: This looks more like a joke, since actually the subimage doesn't even appear in the mainimage. Now if you mean an object (=>bottle) appears in the mainimage, that's a completely different story.

Answer (score 1):

The Imagick class , Check this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php)

Using Imagick::compareImages() to Compare images and display the reconstructed image .

```
<?php

$image1 = new imagick("image1.png");
$image2 = new imagick("image2.png");

$result = $image1->compareImages($image2, Imagick::METRIC_MEANSQUAREERROR);
$result[0]->setImageFormat("png");

header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $result[0];

?>
```

Comment: This makes **no** allowance for shifts, rotations, or most importantly **differences in scale** so it has no chance of working with the supplied images.

Comment: @Mark Setchell Be aware OP edited his question heavily after I flagged it as a duplicate

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$img1 = md5(file_get_contents($img1));
$img2 = md5(file_get_contents($img2));
```

And compare both

Comment: That cannot work! It merely checks whether two images are identical, bit for bit, not whether one image is a sub image of another.

Comment: Confirmed. OP edited his question heavily after I flagged it as a duplicate.

Comment: @mayersdesign please remove flagged. because i think not get a right answer of this same. i have edited and this is totally unique.

Comment: @Manish Patolia I removed the flag some days ago, where are you seeing it?

Comment: @mayersdesign i can see "This question may already have an answer here:" and question url. you can see this?

Comment: No i cannot see it

Comment: PNG is compressed, meaning that even a slightly different pixel will cause a completely different file, on top of that md5 is not meant for comparing similarities. This code will **never** work.